# Difference between "load word" and "load linked word" in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, microcontroller, instruction-set, mips32

I am wondering if somebody could explain to me the difference between the `LW (load word)` and the `LL (load linked word)` instructions are in MIPS? I cannot seem to find any online sources that distinguish the two from each other and my book does not seem to distinguish them form each other either at the moment. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LL` instruction is part of the [load linked / store conditional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load-link/store-conditional) instruction pair, which is used for synchronization in multiprocessor environments.

Unless you are specifically writing SMP synchronization code, ignore `LL`, and use `LW` in all situations.